# I have implemented Adobe Analytic for my client. I read the response from network panel of browser through php

Tags: php, adobe-analytics

I want to fetch the response from adobe analytics which I get in network panel of browser and display in it the page. This there any way to read the response through php. I don't have access to core files. i work as third party implementation team.

Comment: your code so far?

Comment: I have not started any code. I am not able to get started on this.

Comment: then don't expect important help from here

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you can't. php is server-side. Assuming you did the standard javascript Adobe Analytics implementation; well that's client-side.  Your server can't see that stuff.

The longer answer is redeploying Adobe Analytics through a server-side implementation. Basically you setup the code but have it point to your server and then you forward it to adobe (proxying), and so now it is exposed to you server-side.

The alternative answer is depending on what it is you are actually trying to accomplish, you can make use of Adobe Analytics' `s.registerPostTrackCallback` function.  Basically it lets you register a callback function to be called after every `s.t` or `s.tl` call, and it gives you the full/final request URL sent to the AA collection server. You can then make an AJAX request to pass it to your server and do whatever with it.  Or since you mentioned displaying it on page, maybe consider using javascript to render it on the page? But if you're looking for actual response stuff (headers, content) well you're out of luck on this option.

The other *other* alternative answer is.. this almost sounds like you are looking to make some kind of browser plugin?  If so, then on a plugin/extension level, the request/response stuff (including header stuff) *is* exposed on that level.  But again, ultimately this is really a client-side solution..

But first step back and more clearly define what it is you are trying to do. Or if you've done that already, then try (more clearly) to convey that here.